# Downloading word document using php codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am downloading a word document using Codeigniter, is there any way to programmatically set the page orientation to landscape automatically?

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control:  must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$center[0]->name."_contactlist.doc\"");
?>
```

Comment: Make a real Word document, and set the orientation as actual property in it. Sending HTML with a fake MIME type won't accomplish anything.

Comment: Set the page orientation when you create the word document.

Comment: i tried the way you said but still it is not behaving as i want. I want that file to be set to landscape automatically, my users do not know how to do it.